# header title with php when download files

Tags: php, header, download, title

Im using php to stream videos from my site , example of video url

```
http://site.com/videoplayback?pkey=04132122085611&hkey=802b48a81816d7686cb1e3bbb01f4b5c&fkey=04132122085611.flv&start=0
```

In this way i have protect and limit download speed, users IP and hiding real url path..

But when users with any download manager download video, title is always videoplayback for any file, here is screen what im mean https://i.stack.imgur.com/tp40W.png

how i can send title tag ? also **videoplayback**? is **videoplayback**.php in this file i have control to all...

and also this is header what i have in **videoplayback**.php

```
header('Pragma: public'); 
header("Content-length: " . filesize($getFsize));
if ($k4 == '.mp4') {
header('Content-Type: video/mp4');
} else {
header('Content-Type: video/x-flv');
}
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes')
```

edit: Good example is youtube, yt have stream url in same way but send title to download menager...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Content-Disposition` header to set the filename:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
```